# handle puppeteer click and waitForNavigation promise on error 500

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Scenario:

After Click on submit button a post navigation occurs, and 3 situations can happen:

1. Ok. Got green image "img-ok"
2. KO1. Navigation response is 200 and got red image "img-red-light"
3. KO3. Navigation response is 500 and got red lock image "img-lock"

This is my code

```
await Promise.all([
            page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "networkidle0"}),
            page.click(BUTTON_SIGN)
        ]
        ).then (ok => {
            if(page.$("img-ok") != null) {
               //Case 1 
            } else { 
               //Case 2
            }
        }).catch (err => {
            //case 3
        })
```

When 3) happens, process does not goes through catch, instead it ends with default timeout.

How can I make it go through catch? Should I follow a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think this doc note for [`page.goto()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) may also be valid for `page.waitForNavigation()`:

> `page.goto` will not throw an error when any valid HTTP status code is returned by the remote server, including 404 "Not Found" and 500 "Internal Server Error". The status code for such responses can be retrieved by calling [`response.status()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#httpresponsestatus).

So maybe try something like this:

```js
const [response] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "networkidle0"}),
  page.click(BUTTON_SIGN)
]);

if (response.status() === 500) {
  //Case 3 
} else if(page.$("img-ok") != null) { 
  //Case 1
} else { 
  //Case 2
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don´t get a response before the timeout. However the error 500 has already happened.

Comment: Than maybe try to provide a minimal code (with the URL) that reproduces the issue so that somebody could dig dipper.